# get the polygon fence for an area from a single point with overpass API

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am interested in retrieving polygonal boundaries for all admin levels given a lat/long point.

I have a point - let's say (34.0500, -118.2500).

I would like to retrieve the city(admin_level=8)/state(admin_level=4)/country(admin_level=2) information along with the polygonal boundaries for each of these levels.

Currently, I am able to get the areas I am interested in using:

```
[out:json];
is_in(34.0500, -118.2500);
out;

{
  "type": "area",
  "id": 3600148838,
  "tags": {   
           "admin_level": "2",
           "border_type": "national",
           "boundary": "administrative",
           "name": "United States of America",
           "type": "boundary",
           "wikidata": "Q30",
           "wikipedia": "en:United States"
          }
},

{
  "type": "area",
  "id": 3600165475,
  "tags": {
           "ISO3166-2": "US-CA",
           "admin_level": "4",
           "boundary": "administrative",
           "name": "California",
           "type": "boundary"
          }
},
{
 "type": "area",
 "id": 3600207359,
 "tags": {
          "admin_level": "8",
          "boundary": "administrative",
          "name": "Los Angeles",
          "place": "city",
          "short_name": "LA",
          "type": "boundary"
         }
}
```

However, I am unsure about how to get the polygonal boundaries for each of these admin_levels. I would like to do it as a single query if possible.

I tried:

```
area[name="Los Angeles"][admin_level=8][boundary=administrative]->.laarea;
rel(pivot.laarea);
out geom;
```

but this it seems to return data for every city in the world with the name "Los Angeles".

Is there a way to perform the above query using area ids from the previous query?
Is there a better way to do this?

I've been using http://overpass-turbo.eu/ to test my queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `is_in` with the rest of your query as shown in the following query:

```
is_in(34.0500, -118.2500);
rel(pivot)[boundary=administrative][admin_level~"^[248]$"];
out geom;
```

This will return all administrative boundaries on level 2, 4 and 8 for your  location  (34.0500, -118.2500). `is_in` will simply produce a list of areas, which is used by the following (pivot).

overpass turbo link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/e01

When using explicit inputsets this can be also written as:

```
is_in(34.0500, -118.2500)->.areas;
rel(pivot.areas)[boundary=administrative][admin_level~"^[248]$"];
out geom;
```